# how to add product link on the checkout page order summary magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1.8, checkout-page, order-summary

I want to add link on the product which is showing in order summary on checkout page.

I have  found HTML code in the file:

`module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\summary\item\details.html`

Code:

```
<div class="product-item-name-block">
            <strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>
            <div class="details-qty">
                <span class="label"><!-- ko i18n: 'Qty' --><!-- /ko --></span>
                <span class="value" data-bind="text: $parent.qty"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How to add href for the product name?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No, didn't get any solutio. Even I didn't try after that.

Answer (score 1):

*You need plugin for  for class for class*

**Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor**

On your plugin class ,you need pass product ***url as parameter of json  object which is used at checkout summary***

Please follow the folder and file from the blog 
http://www.blogtreat.com/magento-2-display-custom-product-attribute-checkout-summary/

Then you need to some changes at

```
$result['quoteItemData'][$index]['brand'] = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('brand')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
```

**to**

`$result['quoteItemData'][$index]['url'] = $product->getProductUrl()`.

Also on new summary.html you  need to put url

```
<strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>
```

Comment: Hi,
I have tried this but after that checkout is not working.

Comment: Okay, i will look on it

Comment: <strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>

how to pass URL?

Comment: have you got anything?

Comment: how to add custom phtml page link in checkout page..please help me.. if i am clicking that it have to redirect to another page

Answer (score 1):

It is working.

In **details.js** I replaced

```
getBrand: function(quoteItem) {
    var item = this.getItem(quoteItem.item_id);
    return item.brand;
},
```

with

```
getUrl: function(quoteItem) {
    var item = this.getItem(quoteItem.item_id);
    return item.url;
},
```

In **details.html** file changed the

```
<strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>
```

to

```
<a target="_blank" data-bind="attr: { href: getUrl($parent) }">
    <strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>
</a>
```

and removed the code

```
<!-- ko if: (getBrand($parent)) -->
<div class="product-item-brand">
    <span class="label"><!-- ko i18n: 'Brand:' --><!-- /ko --></span>
    <span class="value" data-bind="text: getBrand($parent)"></span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: I tried your solution but didn't work. `item.url` is null/undefined.